# how can i set visibility property of radiobutton

Tags: android, xamarin, visibility

I have problem with `RadioButton` in xamarin. I would like to make my `RadioButtons` visible but I don't know how to do this. My `RadioButtons` are invisible in my xml file. I would like to make them visible from code. I need this because I want to make a list of the last logon users and when I choose one he fill my boxes. But on start I dont have 3 users but only 1 so I need to hide not used RadioButtons. So how can I change property of my RadioButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a radio button visible:

```
radioButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To make a radio button invisible:

```
radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This works fine presuming you have correctly initialized `radioButton` in Activity.

For Xamarin.Android C# try this:

```
button.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
```

[Reference link 1](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15287/doesn-t-have-access-to-setvisibility-to-a-button) and [Reference link 2](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Views.View.Visibility)

Comment: I write in Xamarin.Android c# and i dont have method setVisibility.

Comment: Try if [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15287/doesn-t-have-access-to-setvisibility-to-a-button) suggestion works @Blackchart

Comment: [Refer this](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Views.View.Visibility) @Blackchart

Comment: Yes!
button.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
It works for my perfectly! You help me a lot! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a pain sometimes, because sometimes you have to dig a little bit deaper, since it does not always work 100%, but the Basic in  Xamarin/C# to use is as follow:

rb.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firstRadio);
rb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I write in Xamarin.Android c# and i don't have method setVisibility.